# How to correctly configure ESLint when having undue warnings in <script setup>?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, vuejs3

When moving in Vue3 from a standard `<script>` to `<script setup>`, I get lots of warnings from ESLint. Specifically, anything declared that is not used within `<script setup>` is flagged with `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`.

A typical example is:

```
WARNING in src/layouts/Infinote.vue:105:8
@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars: 'NoteComponent' is defined but never used.
    103 | import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
    104 | import { useQuasar } from 'quasar'
  > 105 | import NoteComponent from 'components/Note.vue'
        |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    106 | import _ from 'lodash'
    107 |
```

for a component that is used in `<template>`.

The "solution" could be to disable `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` globally - but it is not a good idea. **Is there a proper way to make ESLint aware of `<script setup>` functionality?**

Answer (score 2):

You can enable [`vue/script-setup-uses-var`](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/script-setup-uses-vars.html) that is made available by the eslint vue plugin (`eslint-plugin-vue`).

Comment: Thanks, I had `recommended` already in place (they include `vue/script-setup-uses-var`) and after your answer I tried all combinations I could think of but the issues are still there (the config file is sourced as the amount of warnings changes as I change the bundles)